# Scheduling a notebook with IBM Analytics as engine

Tags: watson-studio

I've created a notebook and setup the execution engine to be a IBM Analytics Engine (https://www.ibm.com/cloud/analytics-engine) however, that particular notebook - does not have the schedule button.

Other notebooks (not running through that service) have a schedule button. Is that a bug or do is scheduling unsupported under these conditions ?

Answer (score 1):

For IAE job scheduling is not supported and thus the button to create and maintain job schedules should be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, and in contrast to regular notebooks, analytics-engine driven notebooks only have the schedule button when the kernel is stopped.  Haven't verified if it actually works (the scheduling popup does open though).